# How do I maintain my skill level when I won't be practicing for a good while?

Tags: practice, violin

violin player here. I've been playing for 5 years, and soon, I will be on a three-week trip where I will be unable to bring my violin with me. I have been practicing almost every day, but I am worried that my skill will degrade over this month, and I want to prevent that as much as possible. Is there anything I can do to preserve it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't worry so much about it!, and 2) yes, there are things you can do to work on musical skills even without an instrument.

First, I wouldn't worry about going without practicing for three weeks. I wouldn't schedule a recital for the day you get back, but you're not going to lose five years of skill in three weeks. People say "it's just like riding a bike" when talking about a skill—usually a physical one—that once learned, is always retained (or quickly recalled after a little practice). Music *isn't* like that—but parts of it are.

Learning an instrument is a mix of physical skills—spatial coordination, so-called "muscle memory", etc.—and cognitive "brain" skills (reading music, "learning" a piece, but also engaging with the physical skills analytically ("that finger is too high, by this much, and *because* it just came from over there"). And all these skills are stored in a mix of long-term and short-term memory. One of the goals is to move things *from* the short-term to the long-term. That's why it's important to *stop* practicing and rest; while we sleep, short-term learning is moved to long-term.

A break of three weeks will interrupt your short-term learning, but it shouldn't degrade your long-term memory. Many musicians have taken longer breaks. Fritz Kreisler, after being a child prodigy, left concert performing for eight years while he studied medicine and enrolled in the army, before eventually returning to a concert career. A 1927 issue of *The Strad* says:

> During his year in the Army Kreisler did not touch his violin, and on the surface it may seem like wasted time, but, given the man and his personality, it is far more possible that the escape from a groove, and the liberal education resulting therefrom, helped to foster those qualities which rase him to a place entirely his own.

But meanwhile, yes, there are ways you can keep your short-term skills refreshed even without access to an instrument. A friend of mine broke his arm during his study at a conservatory and couldn't play for several months, so he had to find ways to advance his skills without actually playing.

Score study is important. In the distinction between short- and long-term skills, it's the physical learning that's more long-term, and the cognitive, analytical learning that's more short-term. You'll forget less about how to move your fingers than you will about the details of the piece you're working on. So bring the music with you! Sit and stare at it, note by note. If you have it, study the "score"—the piano accompaniment part, or if it is a a piece for orchestra, the full conductor's score. You may notice new things about how the piece is put together. Try following along in the music while listening to recordings (preferably several different performers). Try going through *without* a recording, simply imagining the sounds. And try miming the actual motions in the air. You might be able to give more careful attention to your technique with the instrument gone than with it present! You can keep an eye on the fluidity of your right wrist, or the posture of your left elbow while shifting.

Comment: The OP doesn't indicate age or current skill level.  Or, for that matter, his current practice routine.  If they're doing 4 hrs/ day and are rapidly rising thru the ranks, a 3-week layoff can take 3 months to get back to where they  are now.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed advice! Will definitely be bringing my music with me.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Actually, I'd disagree, even having been in that position. I could see the *timing* of a break matter, if one were competing with peers for an upcoming audition, and they got 3 weeks "ahead" of you, but in the grand scheme of things, thinking solely of one's violinistic and personal wellbeing, I could imagine encouraging a break of a few weeks, much like the Strad's hint that it helped Kreisler break out of a rut. And it would take focused work to recover, but with a 4-hr-a-day regimen, I would estimate more like a recovery time of weeks rather than months.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much in the way of details.  If you're climbing K-2, yeah, out of luck.  If you're going to a resort, consider buying a "practice violin," of which there are several brands.  Typically they have no body & thus take up relatively little volume compared w/ a standard violin, and are not at all loud so you won't annoy other vacationers.

Comment: I saw your comment above on the previous answer, and I can answer that I am sixteen years old and midway through Suzuki book 5. While I hadn't considered purchasing a practice violin, I don't think that will be feasible for me, but I appreciate your suggestion.